# Using PHP DOMDocument - extract all data between each h2

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

If I have a structure like this:

```
<h2>Title</h2>
<p>Some content</p>
<a href="/test">A bit more content</a>
<a href="/test2">Another link</a>

<h2>Another title</h2>
<p>More content</p>

<h2>One more title</h2>
<p>Last content element</p>
<img src="/hello.jpg" />
```

What's the best way for me to get all content between the h2s?

So my output would be an array containing all content (so for instance the p tags and the a tags, and images should they exist) between each set of tags. So I'd have the content between the first h2 and the second h2, and the content between the second h2 and the third h2. and so on.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Any good suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use Jquery to select the element you want. It has many usefull function for DOM manipulation

Comment: Might have to try this. Thanks very much.

Comment: What type of data you want to store in array? Plain text of element or dom?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `$text = $dom->getElementsByTagName('h2');` ?

Comment: I need the content that is present AFTER the h2 tag and BEFORE the next h2 tag. Sorry if my question wasn't clear.